# golang x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey vs x509.MarshalPKCS1PublicKey()

Tags: go, rsa, pkix

Can anyone help me understand the difference between MarshalPKIXPublicKey() and MarshalPKCS1PublicKey()?

according to the comment:
// MarshalPKIXPublicKey serialises a public key to DER-encoded PKIX format.

// MarshalPKCS1PublicKey converts an RSA public key to PKCS#1, ASN.1 DER form.

what is a DER-encoded PKIX format ?

Thanks

Comment: PKCS1 only supports RSA, PKIX aka SubjectPublicKeyInfo is slightly more complex and supports any kind of public key. PKIX is the format implied by Java's X509EncodedKeySpec and is returned by Java's PublicKey.getEncoded()

Comment: thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't make clear how much you don't (or do) understand. To start from the basics:

[**ASN.1**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) (Abstract Syntax Notation One) is a general scheme for defining the structure of data to be communicated or interchanged between systems or programs.

[**DER**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#DER_encoding) (Distinguished Encoding Rules) is a scheme defined to encode ASN.1 data to sequences of bytes that can be communicated and/or stored, and decode those sequences of bytes back to ASN.1 data losslessly.

**PKCS1** aka RFCs 2313,2437,3447,[8017](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017) (Public Key Cryptography Standard #1) is a standard that defines a range of things about using the RSA algorithm, among which [Appendix A](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#appendix-A.1.1) defines an ASN.1 structure named `RSAPublicKey` to represent an RSA public key, which like any ASN.1 structure can be DER-encoded.

> MarshalPKCS1PublicKey converts an RSA public key to PKCS#1, ASN.1 DER form.

clearly means the DER encoding of the ASN.1 structure for an RSA public key in PKCS1.

[**PKIX**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) (Public Key Infrastructure X.509) is an Internet variant (formally, a profile) of the X.509 standard originally defined by then-CCITT now-ITU-T, currently in [rfc5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280). X.509, and PKIX, primarily defines a format for a public-key **certificate** which binds a public-key to an identity along with other metadata. To do this it has to contain a representation of a public-key that can handle multiple public-key algorithms, which is done using the [`SubjectPublicKeyInfo` structure](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1) which, fairly simply, consists of [an AlgorithmIdentifier that identifies the algorithm, plus a BIT STRING that contains the actual public-key value in an algorithm-dependent manner](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.2.7). The algorithm-dependent part for RSA is specified in [rfc3279 sec 2.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3279#section-2.3.1) and as you see it is the RSAPublicKey strucuture from PKCS1, DER encoded.

Thus 'DER-encoded PKIX format' *of an RSA public key* means the DER encoding of a PKIX/X.509 SubjectPublicKeyInfo structure containing the algorithmIdentifier for RSA (OID 1.2.840.113549.1.1.1 and parameters NULL) and a BIT STRING containing the DER encoded PKCS1 RSAPublicKey.

Related or similar (although most include private not public and/or PEM not DER):
[How to store/retrieve RSA public/private key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193529/how-to-store-retrieve-rsa-public-private-key)
[How do we convert a String from PEM to DER format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4032985/how-do-we-convert-a-string-from-pem-to-der-format)
[Problem transmiting a RSA public key, javaME , bouncy castle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739662/problem-transmiting-a-rsa-public-key-javame-bouncy-castle/)
[Generating RSA keys in PKCS#1 format in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611383/generating-rsa-keys-in-pkcs1-format-in-java)
[How to generate PKCS#1 RSA keys in PEM Format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783366/how-to-generate-pkcs1-rsa-keys-in-pem-format)
[Converting RSA keys into SubjectPublicKeyInfo Form from BigIntegers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18995687/converting-rsa-keys-into-subjectpublickeyinfo-form-from-bigintegers)
[Convert a X509 Public key to RSA public key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31685734/convert-a-x509-public-key-to-rsa-public-key)
[Load public key to create rsa object for public encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123969/load-public-key-to-create-rsa-object-for-public-encryption)
and cross-stack:
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/19149/what-is-the-technical-name-for-a-public-key-container-in-der-format
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/54121/rsa-key-differences-openssl-cli-vs-openssl-ssl-h-c-function