# Saving Privatekey (PKCS8) & Publickey (X509) into PEM Files and reading them in Java

Tags: go, cryptography, rsa, pem

I am generating a key pair in Koltin and saving them into two files, when trying to read these files in any other language than go, it causes and error "Invalid key format".

Here the go Code which generates the keys, encodes them and saves them into pem files. The privatekey should be PKCS8 encoded and the publickey X509 encoded.

```
func ExportPublicKeyAsPemStr(pubkey *rsa.PublicKey) string {
    pubkeyPem := string(pem.EncodeToMemory(&pem.Block{Type: "RSA PUBLIC KEY",Bytes: x509.MarshalPKCS1PublicKey(pubkey)}))
    err := createFile("C:/tmp/publickey.pub", pubkeyPem)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return pubkeyPem
}
func ExportPrivateKeyAsPemStr(privatekey *rsa.PrivateKey) string {
    privatekeyBytes, err := x509.MarshalPKCS8PrivateKey(privatekey)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    privatekeyPem := string(pem.EncodeToMemory(&pem.Block{Type: "RSA PRIVATE KEY",Bytes: privatekeyBytes}))
    err = createFile("C:/tmp/privatekey.key", privatekeyPem)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return privatekeyPem
}
func ExportMsgAsPemStr(msg []byte) string {
    msgPem := string(pem.EncodeToMemory(&pem.Block{Type: "MESSAGE",Bytes: msg}))
    err := createFile("C:/tmp/message.pem", msgPem)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return msgPem
}
func main() {
    bits := 2048
    flag.Parse()
    //args := flag.Args()
    //m:=args[0]
    bobPrivateKey, _ := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader,bits)

    bobPublicKey := &bobPrivateKey.PublicKey
    fmt.Printf("%s\n",  ExportPrivateKeyAsPemStr(bobPrivateKey))
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", ExportPublicKeyAsPemStr(bobPublicKey))
    message := []byte("This is a message with confidential text")
    label := []byte("")
    hash := sha256.New()
    ciphertext, _ := rsa.EncryptOAEP(hash, rand.Reader, bobPublicKey, message,label)
    fmt.Printf("%s\n",ExportMsgAsPemStr(ciphertext))
    plainText, _:= rsa.DecryptOAEP(hash, rand.Reader, bobPrivateKey, ciphertext, label)
    fmt.Printf("RSA decrypted to [%s]", plainText)
}

func createFile(name string, data string) error {
    f, err := os.Create(name)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer f.Close()
    _, err = f.WriteString(data)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Here some sample content of the two pem files:
Privatekey:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Publickey:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBCgKCAQEAwekyN7zVvPmg8cs5COQBSIHujvKjzdg0ku27Z8MdwJDFpi4Nj2Os
uaHLNK4maUile3xQiffiVYQtq3EplehBmquK+ph63F9upv+WDDZPvd5NRN9ENyZR
cqEpEwds87fKij9K774pjHCOerskYiNC7hnZVKkGeHNMocopsh5rOL3XOiGNzwRR
e1fgCqVpMk5lpVH38ffO60afZY3n89u3bKqr99SbyYQVbUFUwIzEgf77ldHMOlSA
a0wViuYv84+jaiqdfDBCa7oKYwT6jBKysdEN6DEOIiIVtf/pLssiGKEiJ0wBEal9
N5xKftFxE47GVCusVMQzrWnhUKjITfRepQIDAQAB
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Now if I for example enter them into this [website](https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/rsa-encryption-decryption) or [this one](https://jwt.io/)(Algorithm RS256) I get an InvalidKeyException...

Could someone tell what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your private key seems to be a Pkcs8-key, but it has the wrong start- and end-line which should be `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` and `-----END PRIVATE KEY-----`. Your public key seems to be a public Pkcs1-key, but not an X.509-key. I suspect that the `MarshalPKIXPublicKey`-method must be used to generate an X.509-key whose start- and end-line is `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` and `-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`. For an overview of the different formats see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49878687/9014097) and [here](https://tls.mbed.org/kb/cryptography/asn1-key-structures-in-der-and-pem).

Comment: The PEM header and footer are indeed correct the way you do it. Also what you suspected proved to be right. Thx a lot